# if..else..if..else code not working properly(coding in C)

Tags: c

I have a question.I think I may have a mistake in my code because my code program(Dev C++) seems not to recognize the "else if" statement.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a = 80;
if(a == 10);
printf("value of a is 10\n");
else if(a == 20);
printf("value of a is 20\n");
else if(a == 30);
printf("value of a is 30\n");
else
printf("none of the values match");
printf("the real value of a is: &d", a);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have semi-colons `;` after the `if` and `else if` statements.

Comment: And `&d` should be `%d`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(a == 10);
           ^
...
else if(a == 20);
                ^
```

Don't add `;` after `if` and all `else if` statements .

**Note** -Also encase last `else` block in `{}` -

```
else{
  printf("none of the values match");
  printf("the real value of a is: %d", a);  // else in any case this will  be printed
}
```

Also note the typo you had `&d` as specifier in `printf` as mentoned in comment by Cool guy .

Comment: And `&d` should be `%d`.

Comment: @CoolGuy  Nice spotting . Didn't see that :|

Answer (score 4):

control structures, such as `if` and `else` don't have semicolons (`;`) after them:

```
if (a == 10) /* here */
    printf("value of a is 10\n");
else if (a == 20)  /* and here */
    printf("value of a is 20\n");
else if (a == 30)  /* and here */
    printf("value of a is 30\n");
else
    printf("none of the values match");
```

To help avoid bugs, it's usually a good idea to surround every block with braces (`{}`):

```
if (a == 10) {
    printf("value of a is 10\n");
} else if (a == 20) {
    printf("value of a is 20\n");
} else if (a == 30) {
    printf("value of a is 30\n");
} else {
    printf("none of the values match");
}
```

And finally, since all the conditions are on the `a` variable, you may want to consider using a `swtich` statement instead of a series of `if`-`else`s:

```
switch (a) {
    case (10):
        printf("value of a is 10\n");
        break;
    case (20):
        printf("value of a is 20\n");
        break;
    case (30):
        printf("value of a is 30\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("none of the values match");
        break;
}
printf("the real value of a is: %d", a);
```

Comment: In each example in first `printf` `;` is missing .

Comment: @ameyCU indeed, copy-paste error :-( Thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.

Comment: Why does the last snippet miss the "else", the `default` section?

Comment: @alk yup, you're right, got distracted while adding it. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Seconded. Also, `astyle --add-brackets` ftw.

Answer (score 3):

You have additional semiconols at the end of "if" and "else if"
Remove then and then try co compile.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using an `if`, then with

```
if (a == 10);
```

the semicolon of `;` ends the `if`. So here:

```
if(a == 10);
printf("value of a is 10\n");
else if(a == 20);
```

you would check whether the value of `a` is 10 and if so, then do nothing. After that, regardless of the value of `a`, you print out that it is 10. And there comes the `else if`, which is not linked to the `if`, because the if was closed by the semi-colon. So, you can fix your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int a = 80;
if(a == 10)
    printf("value of a is 10\n");
else if(a == 20)
    printf("value of a is 20\n");
else if(a == 30)
    printf("value of a is 30\n");
else
printf("none of the values match");
printf("the real value of a is: %d", a);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

or, in a more elegant manner, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int a = 80;
if(a == 10) {
    printf("value of a is 10\n");
} else if(a == 20) {
    printf("value of a is 20\n");
} else if(a == 30) {
    printf("value of a is 30\n");
} else {
    printf("none of the values match");
}
printf("the real value of a is: %d", a);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1)`&d` should be `%d` 2)`system` requires `stdlib.h` 3)Indent your code properly

Comment: @CoolGuy, thank you for pointing out the bugs, I have edited the answer accordingly. I do not intend to change the indent too much, since I want to keep it more-or-less in the style the op has written it.